# argmax from probability distribution better policy than random sampling from softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to train Echo State Network for text generation with stochastic optimization along the lines of Reinforcement learning, where the optimization depends on the reward signal.

I have observed that during evaluation, when I sample from the probability distribution, the bleu score is bigger than when I argmax from the distribution. The difference is almost more than 0.10 points (BLEU Score is generally between the range 0 and 1 ).
I am not sure why does that happen.
Help needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use the argmax function as it is a deterministic approach. And the main issue with that is that it can easily get you trap into a loop. Meaning that in case of an error in the text generation you are likely to keep going on this path without any possibility to get out. The randomness allows a "jump out" of the loop.

A good example to illustrate this need of a jump out is for example the Page Rank algorithm. It uses a random walk parameter that allows the imaginary surfer to get out of dead ends.

The TensorFlow team says about this in their tutos this (without any justification)
:

> Note: It is important to sample from this distribution as taking the argmax of the distribution can easily get the model stuck in a loop.

Comment: How is argmax function a deterministic approach? Can you please elaborate on that point?

Comment: `np.argmax([0.3, 0.2, 0.5])` # deterministic as it returns `2` every time;

`np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], [0.3, 0.2, 0.5])`  # ~ half of the times it returns `2` but it can return `0` or `1`;